# Jekyll blog post links to pdf?

Tags: pdf, jekyll

Is there a way to link a blog post directly to a pdf, instead of going to the html page.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
      <li>
        <span class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>
        <h2>
          <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h2>
        {{ post.excerpt }}
      </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to use a different url for the `post.url` field so that if the user clicks on the post link he directly goes to the pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a custom variable in posts that needs to be linked to a document and then conditionally link to the post or to the document.

Your post

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Post one"
docurl: assets/pdf/test.pdf
---

this the post excerpt

this is the maybe useless post body
```

Your posts list :

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.docurl %}
      <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.docurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {{ post.excerpt }}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But I think that an other question arise : what about User eXperience (UX) ?
You really need to clearly indicate that your link is going to open a pdf and not a page.